# How can I get taller and be mucular at the same time?

Tags: weightlifting, exercise, bodybuilding, exercise-equipment

I'm 15 and I was wondering if I can do weight training and workouts but without stunting my growth because that's what I hear a lot that this happens with teens if they start this so advice?
(Also Idon't know if this is a myth or something so you know anything helps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a complete myth: there is absolute no evidence to suggest that weightlifting may stunt your growth. The reason that this myth came about was that by exercising, your body requires more calories and nutrients to make up for the increased rate of exertion therefore if you don't consume enough then your growth may be impacted.

Comment: Do you have a reference for your claims about energy and nutrition?